# Filling dojo combobox with json data

Tags: json, combobox, dojo, store

I have a json object retrieved from a method which contains user information. I want to set that json object as a store of a dojo combobox. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to use a single object as the store of a combobox (so it would only give 1 option?). If you're trying to use an array of JSON objects as a JSON store, I suggest looking at [enter link description here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/ComboBox.html#programmatic-example-using-a-dojo-store).

As you can see they have a store with inside the `data` attribute an array of JSON objects.

```
new Memory({
    data: [
       ...
    ]
});
```

Then they create a `ComboBox` and the most important things are the `store` and  the `searchAttr` properties. With the `store` property you can connect your store to the combobox and with the `searchAttr` property you can say which property of your JSON object is the visible thing that should be displayed in your combobox.